# postgres cluster not starting

Tags: postgresql

Below is the error message  I am getting

```
waiting for server to start..../bin/sh: line 0: exec: 9999: not found

postgres@ip-172-31-37-228:~/data>  pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -p 9999
waiting for server to start..../bin/sh: line 0: exec: 9999: not found
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

I tried changing port number sill not working

Comment: So what's in the Postgres log?

Comment: What distribution is that? How did you install PostgreSQL? Is `pg_ctl` a shell script in your installation? If yes, what is in it?